# JQUERY: On change select box update number of text inputs on form based on select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

HTML

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input id="bla" type="text" name="attendant[]">
```

JQuery

```
$("select").change(function() {

    var select = parseFloat($('#select').val());
    $('#bla').after('<br><input id="bla" type="text" name="attendant[]">');

 });​
```

Hi guys,  above is the code I created.
I need the select box on change to update the the number of form field base on the value of the select box. If user change to 4 there should be 4 form field display on screen. If value change to 1 there should only be one on the screen.

Not so good with JQuery just started few days ago so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the JSFiddle I'm working on.
http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/b5Gqg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
   <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="template" style="display:none">
   <input type="text" name="attendant[]" />
</div>
<div id="container" >

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("select").change(function() {

    var select = parseInt($('#select').val() , 10);
    var $clone = $('.template').clone().html();
    console.log($clone);
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 0;i< select ; i++){
        html += $clone;
    }
    $('#container').empty().html(html);
 }).change();​
```

You can achieve the same without using `.clone()` .. That was unnecessary..

```
$("select").change(function() {

    var select = parseInt($('#select').val() , 10);
    var $clone = $('.template').html();
    var html = '';
    while(select > 0){
        html += $clone;
        select--;
    }
    $('#container').empty().html(html);
 }).change();​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/b5Gqg/7/)**

**[Without clone](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/b5Gqg/8/)**

Comment: I think you guys misunderstand me... I need to update the number of form field in the page onchange select box not the value of the form field.

Comment: Thanks this works good! Why do you need to do the console.log($clone) and why is there a 10 at the end of the var select. And how does the empty function work.. Just trying to understand what's going on with the code. oh and why do you need the display:none?

Comment: @Jangui .. console.log() is used to log the data to the console of the browser.. That is not necessary ... The 10 in the parseInt(number , 10) is the radix which tells to convert the number to decimal .. The template for the input is stored inside the div with class template . I am setting it to display:none as it is not required to show to the user how the model looks like

Comment: @Suhanth One more thing what do you mean by it is not required to show to the user?

Comment: Check what happens if you remove the display:none .. We base the template as a model and then based on the number populate them..

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b5Gqg/6/

```
var bla = $('#bla');
$("select").change(function(){
    var len = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('input').remove();
    while(len--) bla.clone().insertAfter('select');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("select").change(function() {

var fieldParent=$('#fields_parent');

$(fieldParent).children().remove();

for(var i=0;i<parseInt($(this).val());i++)
{
        $('<input type="text" id="txtInput_' + i + '"></input>').appendTo(fieldParent);
}
```

});

Updated same on jsfiddle.